# Resizable Grids in Accordion Container

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have 3 grids within an accordion container.
I add the `resizable` property to true to all 3 grids.

But when I try to resize any of the Grids, they are instead dragged up or down, instead of growing, and taking up the space.

What could be wrong?

```
Ext.define('MCS.view.task.Mygrid', {    
    requires: ['MCS.view.task.Mytoolbar'],
    extend: 'MCS.view.base.grid',
    alias: 'widget.myGrid',

    itemId: 'myGrid',
    stateId: 'myGrid',
    iconCls: 'icon-application',
    cls: "mcs-header2 mcs-accordion-item  x-docked-noborder-top mcs-border-bottom",
    bodyCls: "mcs-grid-body",
    collapsible: true,
    border: true,
    hideMode: 'offsets',

    resizable: true,

    flex: 1,

    store: 'task.My',

    viewConfig: {
        loadMask: false
    },

    dockedItems:
    [
       //stuff here
    ]
});
```

Accordion ( the 3rd grid is added dynamically to the bottom of the accordion )

```
xtype: 'container',
    flex: 3,
    layout: { type: 'accordion', border: false, multi: true, fill: false },
    items: [
        { xtype: 'myGrid' },
        { xtype: 'pendingGrid' }
    ]
```

Comment: post also accordion code pls

Comment: I added the code for the accordion container. I noticed that if I remove the `flex` property from the grids, then the resizing works, but then the original size and positioning of the grids get messed up.

Comment: According to the document `flex : Number
This configuration option is to be applied to child items of the container managed by this layout. Each child item with a flex property will be flexed (horizontally in hbox, vertically in vbox) according to each item's relative flex value compared to the sum of all items with a flex value specified. Any child items that have either a flex = 0 or flex = undefined will not be 'flexed' (the initial size will not be changed).`

Comment: Can't the `flex` property be overriden with the `resizable` property?

Comment: Dear herman, you should decide which layout property you want to use, `hbox` or `vbox`. If your container dynamically resizing vertically, then you should use `vbox` layout. If you set this layout property on accordion component then all child items, like grid panel, height property will calculate automatically. Of course, if you set `flex` property for child items/components.

Comment: try this link examples, http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html